# Magento 2 Speeding up apache response time

Tags: magento2, apache, response

Hi i am customizing a magento theme Porto on my local machine. I am using wamp 2.4.23 on PHP 7.

Apache is working very slow and its taking 4-5 mins to load a single page. i have to develop the module that why i disabled the configuration and layout cache and set the mode to developer. any recommendation/suggestion regarding how i can speed up the apache server to run the magento 2 application on developer mode ?

Comment: Windows is unsupported platform.  Maybe better to use linux (for example in virtual machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that Magento already has announced their Devbox consisting of docker container in order to develop extension for Magento2 on windows platform.

Alanket has the awesome [GitHub](https://github.com/alankent/magento2devbox-skeleton) documentation on how to install and setup Magento devbox on Windows/Mac Machine.

Answer (score -1):

porto has a major issue with the menu. On each page reload it runs 400 query for desktop view and 400 query for mobile view, even if you view the site from desktop.
You eather dump the included menu module with other, either you hack the menu and instead of query the db to know thw menu items, make it generate and read from am html file..

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for responding, i already done disabling the menu controller but cant help with the response time.

Comment: Why down voting??